# Add active class after page load

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nav

I've been working on a custom menu in a wordpress website. This is why I can't use the standard worpress selector for active menu item. I want to add an active class to the active link. This is my html:

```
<div class="nav">
<ul id="menu">
 <li><a href="/item1">item1</a></li>
 <li><a href="/item2">item2</a></li>
 <li><a href="/item3">item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.nav ul#menu li a').on('click', function(event) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

Everything works fine, it adds the class, but then the page is reloaded and the class is deleted. Is there a way to add the class to the active element when the page is refreshed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Backend using php ? if you dont have access, so use localstorage or cookies !

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how would I do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="/item1" class="active">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/item2">item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/item3">item3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
    var selected_parent;
    if(document.readyState === 'interactive'){
        selected_parent = $('#menu').children().find('a').filter('.active').parent('li').index();
        jQuery.data( document.body, "selected_parent", selected_parent);       
    }
    if(document.readyState === 'complete'){ 
        var selected_parent = jQuery.data( document.body, "selected_parent" );
        $('#menu').children('li:eq('+selected_parent+')').children('a').addClass('active');
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Several ways. Store the info in `localStorage` or cookies, or append it to the URL via a hash.

Here's the hash approach. On click, we append the index of the clicked `li` to the hash, e.g. `my_page.html#3`.

```
$(function() {

    //grab menu and listen for clicks...
    var menu = $('div.nav ul#menu');
    menu.on('click', 'li a', function() {

        //...highlight, and log parent LI's index in URL hash
        $(this).addClass('active');
        location.hash = $(this).closest('li').index();
    });

    //onload, auto-highlight a previously-selected link? Trigger a click on it if so.
    var active_onload = location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');
    if (active_onload) menu.find('li:nth-child('+active_onload+') a').trigger('click');
});
```

Then, on DOM ready, we check the hash to see if we need to highlight the one that was previously selected.

This assumes hashes aren't used for internal links in the page. If they are, a `localStorage` approach (using the same principles, but storing in `localStorage` rather than URL hash) would be better.